# Try - except clause, NoSuchElementExcepts error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, try-except, nosuchelementexception

Actually this is my second question on the same subject.
But in the original question, I put so many functions in my code which played a role as distraction.
So in this post, I deleted all the unnecessary functions and focused on my problem.

What I want to do is as follwing:
1. open a url with the firefox browser(using selenium)
2. click into a page
3. click every thumnails using a loop until the loop hit the "NoSuchElementExcepts" error
4. stop the loop when the loop hit the error

Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#1. opening Firefox and go to an URL
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.amazon.com/Kraft-Original-Macaroni-Microwaveable-Packets/dp/B005ECO3H0"
driver.get(url)
action = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(5)

#2. going to the main images page
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#landingImage').click()
time.sleep(2)

#3 parsing the imgs and click them
n = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    try:  
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'#ivImage_{n}').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver,20,1).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "fullscreen"))
        )
        n = n + 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

driver.close()
```

and error stacktrace is like this

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: Unable to locate element: #ivImage_6
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pythonworkspace\except_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'#ivImage_{n}').click()
```

FYI, all the thumnail images are under [ivImage_"number"] ID
I don't know why my try-except statement is not working. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: I couldn't duplicate your error -- worked for me. To simplify your logic, I would suggest your loop should be: `for n in itertools.count(0):` Right now you are limited to 9 thumbnails. If that is what you truly want, then: `for n in range(9):`. Variable `i` serves no purpose.

Comment: @Booboo Thank you for your reply. Anyways I don't understand what my computer's(?) problem is. It is frustrating :(